# Set privilages to certain database for newly created user

Tags: mysql

I have `foo_bar_test` database existing on my mysql server on host `127.0.0.1`.

But there's no user that can access it but root, and I don't want to use root user anywhere in my code. So I created new user, `fb_test`, and granted him privileges for this database:

```
create user fb_test@'127.0.0.1' identified by password 'some_password';
grant all on 'foo_bar_test.*' to fb_test@'127.0.0.1';
flush privileges;
```

Ok, that should work, but when I log in as this user, I don't have any database available!

What's wrong?

I checked it using show grants for `fb_test@'127.0.0.1'`, but it shows some strange results:

```
grant usage on *.* to fb_test@'127.0.0.1' identified by password '*another_password_dont_know_which_one'
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

you have an error in grant statement. Use the query:

```
grant all on 'foo_bar_test'.* to fb_test@'127.0.0.1';
```

In fact your grant command results an error which I think you ignored.